# RestSharp is not serializing entity/object

Tags: c#, serialization, restsharp

I'm trying to Post a request using Restsharp Client (version 108.0.3), however I'm getting an error of "Bad Request: Some of mandatory fields are missing". I know the reason the error message is showing is due to the values not being passed / sent with the request. I have tried sending in the values multiple ways, however with only one way being successful (but, this way won't work as I need to do some logic before passing the entity).

For now, I'm trying to send in only 2 values:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserModel : IBdeoModel
{
    [Required]
    //[property: JsonPropertyName("name")]
    [DataMember(Name = "email")]
    public string ClientEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //[property: JsonPropertyName("password")]
    [DataMember(Name = "password")]
    public string ClientSecrent { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool IsNameValue => true;
}
```

When the code is run, the folling code will be the first step to "setup" some data. A transport model is created to do some logic for data conversion depending on type (e.g. string, int, datetime) - for this step it is primarily to get the password in the required format.

```
public class BdeoLoginAPI : ApiRoutable, IBdeoLoginApi
{
    private readonly IClient _client;
    public override string MidRoute => "/prod/v2/login";

    public BdeoLoginAPI(IClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticates the request to Bdeo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param cref="UserModel">User Auth Model</param>
    /// <returns>The result set of properties created in hubspot.</returns>
    public UserTokenModel<LoginAuthDetails> AuthenticateBdeo(UserModel entity)
    {
        string path = GetRoute<UserModel>();
        BdeoTransportObject<UserModel> transportModel = new BdeoTransportObject<UserModel>(entity);
        //return _client.Execute<UserTokenModel<LoginAuthDetails>, UserModel>(path, entity, Method.Post);
        return _client.Execute<UserTokenModel<LoginAuthDetails>, BdeoTransportObject<UserModel>>(path, transportModel, Method.Post);
    }

}
```

The transport model that is being called:

```
    [DataContract]
public class BdeoTransportObject<T> : BdeoTransportModel<T>
{
    public BdeoTransportObject() { }

    public BdeoTransportObject(T model)
    {
        ToPropertyTransportModel(model);
    }
}

    [DataContract]
public abstract class BdeoTransportModel<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
  
    internal void ToPropertyTransportModel(T model)
    {
        var propertiesToAdd = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        PropertyInfo[] modelProperties = model.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo modelProp in modelProperties)
        {
            var memberAttrib = modelProp.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute)) as DataMemberAttribute;
            object modelValue = modelProp.GetValue(model);

            if (modelValue == null || memberAttrib == null || modelValue.ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                continue;
            }

            //some other logic

            propertiesToAdd.Add(memberAttrib.Name, modelValue);
        }

        Properties = propertiesToAdd;
    }
}
```

Then finally doing the actual RestRequest call.

```
     public T Execute<T, K>(string absoluteUriPath, K entity, Method method = Method.Get) where T : new()
        => SendReceiveRequest<T, K>(absoluteUriPath, method, entity);

    private RestRequest ConfigureRequestAuthentication(string path, Method method)
    {
        string fullPath = $"{BasePath.TrimEnd('/')}/{path.Trim('/')}";
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(fullPath, method);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        
        return request;
    }

    private T SendReceiveRequest<T, K>(string path, Method method, K entity) where T : new()
    {
        RestRequest request = ConfigureRequestAuthentication(path, method);

        if (!entity.Equals(default(K)))
        {
            //string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity);
            //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
            //request.AddJsonBody(entity);
            //string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, Formatting.Indented);
            request.AddBody(entity);
            //request.AddParameter("text/json", entity, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }

        var response = _client.Execute<T>(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed with " + response.StatusCode.ToString() + ". Error Message: " + response.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return response.Data;
    }
```

When sending the entity through, the data is definately present, however it seems it is not serializing as it should and throwing the error of BadRequest - mandatory fields are missing.

[image]

However, when I take out the middle step for the transport model, it works fine. Making the necessarily alterations to get it to work looks like this:

```
  [DataContract]
public class UserModel : IBdeoModel
{
    [Required]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool IsNameValue => true;
}

    public UserTokenModel<LoginAuthDetails> AuthenticateBdeo(UserModel entity)
    {
        string path = GetRoute<UserModel>();
        BdeoTransportObject<UserModel> transportModel = new BdeoTransportObject<UserModel>(entity);
        return _client.Execute<UserTokenModel<LoginAuthDetails>, UserModel>(path, entity, Method.Post);
       // return _client.Execute<UserTokenModel<LoginAuthDetails>, BdeoTransportObject<UserModel>>(path, transportModel, Method.Post);
    }
```

It seems that adding these properties to a dictionary type in the transportmodel is causing the issue when Restharp attempts to serialize it, however I can't seem to see what is wrong to get it to work.

Comment: Why do you need that complexity at all? When your server expects a UserModel then simply send it a UserModel.

Comment: @Ralf, The reason for that complexity is because the same code will be used to call various different api endpoint with different models (for sending to the api endpoint and to receive different models back). For the transport model, depending on the type or which api endpoint will be called a different transportmodel will be called. This will eliminate having to created a lot of code with the same functionality, but just having the models (e.g. UserModel) different.

Comment: @Ralf, Please add your comment as an answer. For this particular instance you are correct - I ran a bit further than just this particular instance (guess I needed some sleep).

Comment: AddBody adds the object. You should use AddJsonBody, which you tried but commented out for some reason. https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addjsonbody